# How to add custom fields to a page

Tags: nodes, entities

Am newbie here. I just have a problem with fields adding them to a page. 
I want fields specificly textboxes and a button to be in a page. This page will be used by my authenticated users. These textboxes will be filled in by the said users then have the system save the info to the DB after click of the button.

How do I do this? I created a content type of this but i can't seem to add them in the page. No article i can find here either that answers my problem. Please help. Am new here and am not a coder. 
Thanks y'all.

Comment: The easiest way, without any programming experience, would be to install the webform module.  Buried deep in the webform options is the ability to create the form as a block, which will allow you to place it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal allows content to go onto your site, such as a Page or Book through a `content type`. If you want to show a Page or Book and embed a field or form on that page that is backed by a database -- typically you have to use another module for that which allows you to embed Forms onto existing Page (Node) content.

To do this usually you can use 1 of the following modules:

[Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform)

> Webform is the module for making forms and surveys in Drupal. After a
>   submission, users may be sent an e-mail "receipt" as well as sending a
>   notification to administrators. Results can be exported into Excel or
>   other spreadsheet applications. Webform also provides some basic
>   statistical review and has an extensive API for expanding its
>   features.
>
> Some good examples could be contests, personalized contact forms, or
>   petitions. Each of these could have a customized form for end-users to
>   fill out. If you need to build a lot of customized, one-off forms,
>   Webform is a more suitable solution than creating content types and
>   using CCK or Field module.

or

[EntityForms](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform)

> The Entityform module enables you to create front-end forms (fieldable
>   entities), which contain fields that you define! These forms use the
>   standard Drupal fields. This means that out of the box, you can use
>   any standard Drupal node field!

These modules allow you to embed any form you define through their admin interface into existing page content.

A key difference is in these forms is that Webforms stores its own data in a custom backend difficult to make into drupal (page) content on your website. While EntityForm since it uses Drupal Fields -- it's submitted content may easily be turned into Drupal site content (but need not be).

Comment: Hi @tenken, thanks. Will try to use both. I really hope one of them works for me. :D